# How to handle DbContext when writing a generic API for EF in an EntityRepository before knowing specific DbContext class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, n-tier-architecture

I am trying to write a generic NTier API Library that I can use in all of my  "Modules" (like UserModule, AccountingModule, etc), which currently use EF but the data access layer shouldn't be hard coupled to EF. The problem is I can't seem to figure out a *good* way to incorporate the DbContext.

My planned structure is to have the generic NTier Library as a standalone project, and then have that be referenced in my Module projects, where are just class libraries and an NTier API written for a certain subject area.

So as an example, here is a snippet of my generic EntityRepository:

```
public class EntityRepository<TClass> : IEntityRepository<TClass> where TClass : Entity, new()
{
    private DbContext Context => //Not sure what to do here.

    public void Delete<TTableClass>(Guid id) where TTableClass : Entity, new ()
    {
        TTableClass record = Context.Set<TTableClass>().Find(id);
        Context.Set<TTableClass>().Remove(record);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Note, TClass is different from TTableClass. Now in my previous iteration of this API, before I decided to split things up into modules, it looked like this:

```
public class EntityRepository<TClass, TTableClass> : IEntityRepository<TClass> where TClass : Entity, new()
    where TTableClass : Entity, new ()
{
    private DbContext Context => EntityDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>.GetInstance();

    protected DbSet<TTableClass> DbSet => Context.Set<TTableClass>();

    public void Delete(Guid id)
    {
        TTableClass record = DbSet.Find(id);
        DbSet.Remove(record);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But this only because it was all one context so I know what the context class is going to be, now I don't know. The obvious answer is to just include the context class as a generic parameter, but this is bad design, because it means my service class will have to have knowledge of the way my repository layer is querying data, bad leaky abstraction. In fact I have done that previously 2 versions ago of my generic API, which looked like this:

```
public abstract class EntityRepository<TClass, TDbContext>
    where TClass : Entity, new ()
    where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private DbContext Context
    {
        get { return EntityContextFactory<TDbContext>.Current(); }
    }
```

But that made my EntityService and specific implementation definitions look like this:

```
public abstract class EntityService<TRepositoryClass, TClass, TDbContext>
    where TClass : Entity, new()
    where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
    where TRepositoryClass : EntityRepository<TClass, TDbContext>

public class UserService : EntityService<UserRepository, User, MyDbContext>
```

Yuck, way too much leaky abstraction. The other problem is I can't just store the DbContext class as a member/property of the class (hence the static factory references above) since I can't guarantee other programmers using my library are using a DI container

In short, how can I make a generic API work if:

1. I don't know the DbContext type in advance.
2. I can't pass DbContext type in as generic parameter on class definition.
3. I can't store the DbContext as a member of EntityRepository.

Comment: `since I can't guarantee other programmers using my library are using a DI container` - this doesn't make sense to me. You should set your library up so anyone can use it, DI-container-user or not. One golden rule in DI, is that all code except the container doesn't know DI is being used.

Comment: And you cannot have a finished generic, non-EF-coupled, data layer which you can magically say to to use EF. At the least, define an abstract generic data layer which you have to derive from to 'fill in the gaps', which gaps are then filled EF specific code.

Comment: @Marteen, that's exactly what I am saying. I shouldn't rely on something using or not using a DI container, so having the DbContext as a constructor is bad. Your second comment is also correct, I think I have something figured out that will work. Will post after testing.

Comment: Why is a DbContext in the constructor (of an EF specific, derived-from-generic-baseclass, class), bad? I do not see the problem.

Comment: Well I guess it could be a matter of usage. I am writing this API for two types of programmers, one who will just use the API as is (IE call the services and that's it) and others who will either swap data access methods, or write their own custom methods. The former shouldn't know or care about the data access method right? Well sticking an EF dbcontext into the constructor means they now have to know about that. They also have to know it's not thread safe because maybe they ARE using a DI container...

Comment: ...or a factory and binding the services as singletons since for thread safe purposes that is a good practice, but for a DbContext, that will destroy you.